# Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DDoS'

Tags: r

I was trying to run a deep learning model on the compressed dataset I retrieved from the bottleneck layer of an autoencoder. The dataset has 4 features and when I appended the target feature, the total features became 5. The target feature is made up of 2 classes which are: DDoS and Benign and I have fitted a random forest model on the dataset and the result was interesting. However, I intend to use a deep learning approach to fit on the dataset but I keep get the error `Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DDoS'`. I decided to run my code line by line to enable me know where the error was coming from and it was coming the line where I tried to convert the target feature to one-hot using `to_categorical()`. Please is there a way I could go about it as I have installed `keras` library and the error has still not cleared?

Here's the code I used

```
 train <- DF2[sample(1:225711, 1*nrow(DF2)),]
>   Train2<- as.matrix(train) #convert datafarame to matrix and remove dimensions
>   dimnames(Train2) <-NULL
>   set.seed(222)
>   #data partition
>   part <- sample(1:225711, 0.8*nrow(Train2), replace = F)
>   training<- Train2[part,1:4]
>   testing <- Train2[-part,1:4]
>   trainingtarget <- Train2[part,5]
>   testingtarget <- Train2[-part,5]
>   trainLabels <- to_categorical(trainingtarget)
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DDoS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh! the target feature was a factor of string values: `Benign and DDoS` and so, immediately I converted the classes to numeric, `0 and 1`, the error was resolved.